# What is the difference between equales and ==

Tags: java

I am new to java, and i was wondering what is the difference between equales and ==,
i know you can over ride equales, and you can't overrdie ==, but how?

Lets say i have java class Dogs, and if dogs are from same kind i want them to be equale, how can i do it?

```
    public class Dogs{
        private String dogKind;

        public Dogs(String kind){
            this.dogKind = kind
        }

        public String getDogKind(){
            return this.dogKind;
        }
     }
```

So where in how i override equales?

Comment: Please try to read and search online before asking a very basic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply read online(So many good answers), and if you dont understand:

You need to add this in the Dogs class, simply do:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!obj instanceof Dogs){
            return false;
        }
        return this.dogKind.equals(((Dogs)obj).getDogKind());
    }
```

The first part makes sure that the object given to the method is not null or from a different class.

The second part simply uses String equals, to check if the Strings are the same or not.

Comment: also you forgot about hashcode

Comment: true, il change it in a sec

Comment: who ever, changed it thank you, i was in the middle of changing it myself :-)

Comment: The `null` check is redundant - if `obj` is `null` `obj instanceof Dogs` will be `false`.

Comment: Idan Arye, are you sure?